# XNA/C# projectiles firing issue - need one projectile at a time to fire on spacebar press

Tags: c, xna-4.0

Problem: Upon spacebar press i need my projectile to fire and continue its life regardless of another press or letting go of the spacebar.

below is both the code adding, updating, and drawing the projectiles. I have tried numerous reworkings of this code but alas am not experienced enough to have found a suitable solution yet.

AddProjectile code below

enter code here

```
//add projectile if spacebar is pressed

private void AddProjectile(Vector2 position)
{
    //i need somthing like this to make bullets autofire on phone
    //while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
    //{
    //    Projectile projectile = new Projectile();
    //    projectile.Initialize(GraphicsDevice.Viewport, projectileTexture, position);
    //    projectiles.Add(projectile);
    //}

   if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) ||
     currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
   {
       Projectile projectile = new Projectile();
       projectile.Initialize(GraphicsDevice.Viewport, projectileTexture, position);
       projectiles.Add(projectile);
   }
}
```

Update Projectile code below

```
private void UpdateProjectiles()
{
    //update projectiles
    for (int i = projectiles.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) ||
            currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {

           //adds particle to first projectile but not again until the next fire butotn press
            //particleEngine.EmitterLocation = new Vector2(projectiles[i].Position.X, projectiles[i].Position.Y);
            projectiles[i].Update();
            projectileOn = true;


        }
        //if projectiles not being fired remove them from the game screen 
        else
        {
            projectiles.RemoveAt(i);
        }



    }

}
```

the Draw method that draws projectiles to screen

```
//draw the projectiles
            //***********************************************************
             //using the if here allows control of projectiles to pass...
             //...to the "currentstate of the spacebar (is pressed = fire)
             /***/

            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) ||
                currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.Count; i++)
                {
                    projectiles[i].Draw(spriteBatch);

                }
            }

            //remove projectiles and reset
            if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space) ||
                currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Released)
            {


                UpdateProjectiles();
            }
```

So, this is what i have so far and as stated can get the projectile to worl fine , i just cant get them to continue their life (until a collision or they reach the end of screen) once i let go of the keyboard spacebar.

Answer (score 1):

A quick overview of the problems I see that are causing your isses:

- You're checking if keys/buttons are pressed during your add, update, and draw methods.
- If a key isn't pressed, you're removing the item during an update and not drawing it during  a draw.

To accomplish what I think you're trying to accomplish, I'd do something along these lines (tailored and cleaned up for your needs, of course):

```
private void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
   // Only add a new projectile if Space or A is pressed
   if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) ||
      currentGamePadState.Buttons.A == ButtonState.Pressed)
   {
      AddProjectile(); // some method that adds a new projectile to 'projectiles'
   }

   // Update all existing projectiles, regardless of button press.
   // This will allow your projectiles to continue flying after they have been fired.
   for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.Count; i++)
   {
      projectiles[i].Update();
      if (projectiles[i].Dead) // check if projectiles[i] is out of bounds or has collided with something
      {
         projectiles.RemoveAt(i);
         i--;
      }
   }
}

private void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
   // Draw all existing projectiles, regardless of button press.
   for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.Count; i++)
   {
      projectiles[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
   }
}
```

Your space bar or A button is only used to *fire* a new projectile.  You want that projectile to fly until it hits something or flies off the side of the screen, and it shouldn't depend on whether you have a button pressed in order to do that.  Neither should drawing the bullet.

Make sense?

Comment: Hi Jodacola, yes thanks that makes complete sense to me now, i willpost back an implementation of your suggestion asap, though now i know this method a little better i am thinking of a rewrite cos me code is abit scribbly and im thinking these can all be reclassified into better parent classes like a sprite manager and logic, input, level manager etc, could i ask you, do you think this type of modularisation is a good way to go , as in the long run , it may prove to be better compartmentalized? advice is always welcome

Comment: @gruffy321 In most cases, compartmentalisation is best. Ideally no two objects should need to know about the other's existence. Of course this is sometimes impossible, but in this case it seems like you could definitely improve your code by redesigning the class structure.

Comment: thanks dude, your opinion obviously meant alot a si have recoded everything now so i can approach handling weponary in a base class that my derived player sprite can access, this i though would create a scenario whereby any sprites can have a projectile ability but do not necesaarily have to use it etc

Comment: I think im starting to get it - he says warily